# manipulating audio input buffer on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, audio, ubuntu, buffer, audio-recording

Suppose that I want to code an audio filter in C++ that is applied on every audio or to a specific microphone/source, where should I start with this on ubuntu ?

edit, to be clear I don't get how to do this and what is the role of Pulseaudio, ALSA and Gstreamer.

Answer (score 1):

[Alsa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture) provides an API for accessing and controlling audio and MIDI hardware.  One portion of ALSA is a series of kernel-mode device drivers, whilst the other is a user-space library that applications link against.  Alsa is single-client.

[PulseAudio](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio) is framework that facilitates multiple client applications accessing a single audio interface (alsa is single-client).  It provides a daemon process which 'owns' the audio interface and provides a IPC transport for audio between the daemon and applications using it.   This is used heavily in open source desktop environments.  Use of Pulse is largely transparent to applications - they continue to access the audio input and output using the alsa API with audio transport and mixing.  There is also  [Jack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JACK_Audio_Connection_Kit) which is targeted more towards 'professional' audio applications - perhaps a bit of a misnomer, although what is meant here is low latency music production tools.

[gStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org) is a general purpose multi-media framework based on the signal-graph pattern, in which components have a number of inputs and output pins and provide a transformation function.  A Graph of these components is build to implement operations such as media decoding, with special nodes for audio and video input or output.   It is similar in concept to CoreAudio and DirectShow.  [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) and [libAV](http://libav.org) are both open source alternatives that operate along similar lines.  Your choice between these is a matter of API style, and implementation language.  gStreamer, in particular, is an OO API implemented in C. VLC is C++.

The obvious way of implementing the problem you describe is to implement a gStreamer/libAV/VLC component.  If you want to process the audio and then route it to another application, this can be achieved by looping it back through Pulse or Jack.

Alsa provides a [plug-in mechanism](http://alsa.opensrc.org/Ladspa_%28plugin%29), but I suspect that implementing this from the ALSA documentation will be tough going.

The de-facto architecture for building effects plug-ins of the type you describe is Steinberg's [VST](http://www.steinberg.net/en/products/vst.html).  There are plenty of open source hosts and examples of plug-ins that can be used on Linux, and crucially, there is decent documentation.   As with a gStreamer/libAV/VLC, you be able to route audio in an out of this.

Out of these, VST is probably the easiest to pick up.

Comment: the problem with VST is that the host is supposed to have a VST plugin infrastructure, i just want to code a filter and then let the user decide to use this filter or not without switching to other apps when keep using the recording app that he is used to.

Comment: @user1824407 From your description and this comment, I understand that you want to apply the filter to arbitrarily to existing application. Due to the proliferation and lack of standardization across Linux desktops, I'm pretty certain you are going to need to intercept audio input, route it to an application that runs the filters, and then back through either Jack or Pulse to applications.